# exist start-stop-daemon program on centos?

Tags: linux, unix, centos, centos6

I google a little about this but I could not find any simple solution, all solutions seems kind like a hack to me.
Do you know guys if exist a program like start-stop-daemon for centos like in ubuntu?.

I try with:

```
  /etc/init.d/functions program stop/start/restart
```

But my problem is that I don't have enough permissions.

Regards.

Comment: You can stop and start services with the `service` command (like, `service sshd stop` or `service sshd restart`), but you still need root privileges to do that.

Comment: I cannot use any root privileges solution, that´s why I´m looking for a program. Also I can kill the process, but I was wondering if exist a more elegant solution on centos, without require root privileges

Comment: It doesn't take root privs to use `service`, but... Most of these daemons will need root privs.  So you may be able to start them, but they will die shortly there after.  Is `sudo` a possibility?

Comment: You can't stop a system service -- or kill the corresponding process -- without root privileges, unless the process happens to be running as your user ID. In all other cases, you will need some mechanism to obtain elevated privileges.  If you don't have that, you're generally out of luck.  It's possible you haven't accurately described your use case and we're answering the wrong question, so feel free to update your question to clarify what you want to do.  Better yet, delete this one and open a new question on, say, http://unix.stackexchange.com/, where it would be on topic.

Comment: The service is started by me user so I have rights to kill the process, but the problem is that seems I cannot with the mechanism that I was doing